# Surjectivity of Pseudo-Riemannian exponential map on geodesically complete manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Suppose one has a geodesically complete pseudo-Riemannian manifold $M$ i.e. the exponential map is defined for all tangent vectors on the manifold. Can one make a sensible statement about whether (or when) the exponential map restricted to some arbitrary tangent space

\begin{equation}
\exp : \text{T}_p M \to M
\end{equation}

for some $p \in M$ will be surjective?

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more specific about what kind of 'sensible statement' you're looking for.  It's known not to be surjective in every case.  A well-known example in which surjectivity fails is the exponential map on $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ endowed with its bi-invariant pseudo-Riemannian metric.   Of course, this is a problem of great interest in relativity, where there are many known cases of failure of surjectivity, each having some physics interpretation in terms of gravitational fields and signaling.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This question is too broad. I will need to do some more research before I can get more specific about the problem in question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RobertBryant Robert, in the case of Lie groups, is there a property that explains the lack of surjectivity of the exponential?